# What happens with transaction when repository is called from completable future supply method?

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, completable-future

My question is: how will transaction behave in a code like this?

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void test(List<Long> ids) {
    List<CompletableFuture> list = ids.stream().parallel()
            .map(id -> build(id))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    // other logic
}

private CompletableFuture build(Long id) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> Calculation.builder().id(id).build(), someExecutor)
            .thenApply(calculationRepository::save);
}
```

I think it will break because a) private method b) other threads

Is there a way to save my transaction? (the code example is synthetic, but the concept should be clear)

Comment: Just try it out :-) But seriously: the save method of the repo will run in it's own transaction. if you call something asynchronous it will always be in it's own transaction.

Comment: If you want it to happen in the same transaction, it has to happen on the same thread. Usually it is not an issue because what you want to parallelize is not DB related: it will be some calculation or performing other I/O. You will just need to synchronize the results back on the transaction thread afterwards in order to persist them.